# How to configure rollup js to bundle node modules commonJs

Tags: typescript, node-modules, bundler, commonjs, rollupjs

I have a simple ts application that I run in the browser.
To bundle the ts files I am using rollup js.

I installed diffusion package

```
npm install diffusion
```

And import the module to my ts file **app.ts**:

```
import * as diffusion from 'diffusion';

diffusion.connect({/* options */});
```

Now when I start the application in the browser I get the following:

```
diffusion.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at diffusion.js:5:23
```

This is the line that causes the error:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

The question is how to bundle a node module that uses commenJs correctly with rollup.

This is my current **rollup.config.mjs** file:

```
import { createSpaConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

const baseConfig = createSpaConfig({
  outputDir: 'dist',
  nodeResolve: { browser: true, dedupe: ['lit-html'] },
  developmentMode: process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH === 'true',
  html: {
    extractAssets: false,
    minify: false,
  },
  injectServiceWorker: false,
  legacyBuild: false,
  workbox: false,
});


export default merge(baseConfig, {
  input: 'index.html',
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      declaration: false,
      sourceMap: false,
      inlineSources: false,
      compilerOptions: {
        target: 'esnext',
      },
    }),
    nodeResolve(),
    commonjs({
      include: /node_modules/,
      sourceMap: false,
    })
  ]
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

##### EDIT

I tried to reproduce the app [here](https://ttps://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/crazy-monad-tn93yr), using parcel (Unfortunately I was not able to start the app with web-dev-server and rollup inside the codesandbox.io, but I provided there the same app structure I am using locally).

the app works fine with parcel, but when I use rollup to build it:

```
npm run build
```

and web-dev-server to start it

```
npm start
```

with the following build and start scripts:

```
{ ...
  "build": "rimraf dist/ && rollup --config"
  "start": "web-dev-server --watch"   
... }
```

I get locally this error: `diffusion.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`
How to fix that using rollup js?

#### EDIT 2

I Just noticed that after building the app. If I add the main.js bundled file to my index.html entry, it works, so basically what I am missing is to configure rollup to inject bundled files into my index.html file but not sure how to add that?

Comment: What's the version of rollup (and other deps) you are using?

Comment: rollup ^3.29.4 ... I provided the app here https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/crazy-monad-tn93yr